# Do I need a "will" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Life began in the sea, and (will) probably going to end on the land.

Sounds good both ways, but I wonder if one is more grammatical than the other?

Or maybe I should write something like this:

> Life began in the sea, and **will** probably end on the land.

Comment: *Will probably gonna* is a bad combination. If I were you, I would have inserted an *is* instead of *will*.

Comment: @MARamezani You nailed it. Post it, Danno!

Comment: But sea levels are rising, so the sea will probably end on the land too.

Comment: @TRomano I think Ebola will be faster, or nuclear weapons.

Comment: *Land* sounds better than *the land* in this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Experimenting possible sentences popping out:

> Life began in the sea, and probably *going to end on the land.

There is no way that gerund will work there. Looking at the sentence, a future structure is needed. A very common form of forming such structure is using **be + going + to**. This is fixed. You can *not* omit anything from it. <sup>1</sup>

> Life began in the sea, and *will probably going to end on the land.

Answering this with a quote from [EnglishPage](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html):

> Simple Future has two different forms in English: "will" and "be going to." Although the two forms can sometimes be used **interchangeably**, they often express two very different meanings.

So, sometimes these forms are interchangeable. That means they are not used together. "Will" + "going to" *is*n't gonna work. The correct form of the sentence goes as following:

> Life began in the sea, and is probably going to end on the land.

Regarding your last sentence:

> Life began in the sea, and will probably end on the land.

Referring back to [the very page](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html):

> **USE 4**: ***"Will" or "Be Going to" to Express a Prediction***
>
> Both "will" and "be going to" can express the idea of a general prediction about the future. Predictions are guesses about what might happen in the future. In "prediction" sentences, the subject usually has little control over the future and therefore USES 1-3 do not apply. In the following examples, there is no difference in meaning.

And that means the last sentence is equally valid.

---

<sub>1: I have seen many learners fall in the trap of omitting one of either *be* or *to* in this simple future structure, and I'm not an analyst or teacher or whatever! At least, that kind of error is frequent here.</sub>